# Cumulative variable to subtract over and over again until it reaches 0 value

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, while-loop, difference

I need help with loops in C++.
Suppose I have 10 people, represented by a vector of length 10, each of them with a certain age. I want to select only people with age<12, and subtract to their age a fixed value `age_fixed`. It looks very simple with a for loop:

```
vector<float> diff_ages(0);
vector<float> ages {1.2, 7.3, 13.9, 17.8, 45., 72.3, 12.1, 100.3, 6.7, 88.2};
double age_fixed=8.1;

for (auto i=0;i<ages.size();i++){
  if (ages[i]<12){
      diff_ages.push_back(ages[i]-age_fixed);
  }
}
```

Now I want to complicate things:

- if the difference between `ages[i]` and `age_fixed` is greater that `0`, I want to put the difference in `diff_ages`, as usual;
- if the difference is lower than `0`, e.g. for `ages[0]`, `ages[1]`, `ages[8]`, I want to put `0` in `diff_ages`, and use a cumulative variable `cum_age` where I sum the exceeding difference (in abs value); if this cumulative variable is greater than 0 at the end of the loop over the 10 ages (in my case `cum_age=9.1` at the end of the first loop), I want to restart the loop again and again, subtracting the values accumulated in `cum_age` from `ages[i]`, until `cum_ages` becomes `0`.

Any idea on how to do that? I think I should use a `while` loop, but I'm not very familiar with it, I usually use for loops.

+++++++++++EDIT+++++++++++

Suppose my `ages` vector is:

```
vector<float> ages {1.3, 7.3, 99.7};
double age_fixed=8.1;
```

Suppose I don't do any selection- i.e. I take all the three ages, without the `if` statement `ages[i]<12`.
At every step of the loop, I will have:

```
i=0
diff_ages[0]=0
cum_ages=abs(ages[0]-diff_ages)=6.9
i=1
diff_ages[1]=0
cum_ages=abs(ages[0]-diff_ages)+abs(ages[1]-diff_ages)=6.9+0.8=7.7
i=2
diff_ages[3]=91.6
cum_ages=7.7
```

Since `cum_ages>0` at the end of the loop, I want to restart the loop and finally subtract `cum_ages` only to `ages[i]>0`, in this case to `ages[2]`. After this second loop, cum_ages=0 and I don't need to restart the loop again, but suppose I had another `ages[i]=7.8`, I would have `cum_ages>0` and restart the loop again.

What I wanty to obtain is the vector `diff_ages` with values greater or, at least, equal to `0`, after exhausting the `cum_ages` value with as loops as it needs.

Comment: `while(cum_age > 0) {//for_loop}`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you please rephrase *"I want to restart the loop again and again, subtracting the values accumulated in cum_age from ages[i], until cum_ages becomes 0."* more explicitly? Also, could you give a desired output, say with an example input with only a few ages (10 people is already a lot; we can start with 3 or 4 people so we can do it by hand to understand what is happening).

Comment: @Stef I updated the question with a practical example. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I still don't understand. What would be the output in your example?

Comment: @Stef the output would be the vector: 
diff_ages = {0.0, 0.0, 83.9}; I don't mind much about the specific output, because I need to apply a similar procedure also to other vectors with other meanings.

Comment: What would be the output if `ages = {1, 1, 1, 1, 3}` and `age_fixed = 2`, and why?

Comment: I suppose an endless loop; I would add an if statement that checks if the values are all equal to zero, than it would exits the loop evn if cum_ages>0 (as in your example).

Comment: Take it one step at a time. **1)** If the difference is lower than `0`, put `0` in `diff_ages`. TEST. **2)** Realize this is getting complicated and move the per-element processing into a helper function. TEST. **3)** Have your function return the value to sum. TEST. **4)** Introduce a variable that sums the return value of your function. TEST. **5)** Figure out what to do if the variable's value is positive at the end of your loop.